# What is the longest distance by car ferry?

Tags: ferries, where-on-earth, extreme-tourism

I just noticed that there is a ferry from [mainland spain to Tenerife](http://www.viamare.com/armas-portimao-tenerife.html). I already knew of the ferry to [Iceland](http://www.smyrilline.com/frontpage-1.aspx).

My question is if there are ferries that travel longer distances than these two?

Comment: [Cadiz–La Palma](http://www.trasmediterranea.es/) is slightly longer than Portimao–Tenerife. Can there be intermediate stops?

Comment: Yes intermediate stops are accepted. The route to Iceland stops on the farroerislands

Comment: How often should it go to be considered a ferry? The 2219 km I found is just three times a year, so maybe it doesn't really count. Bergen–Kirkenes does, but it does a much longer distance than driving would, and is closer to a cruise-ship than to a ferry in practice.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**[Omsk – Salekhard](https://severflot.ru/raspisanie-passazhirskie-perevozki/omsk-tobolsk-salekhard-i-obratno) 2783 km, 6 days**.  Currently as of 2018.  River boat.  I don't know if it takes cars.

---

Some sea or ocean crossings that are longer than 1000 km, as the crow flies (current as of 2012):

- [Travemünde–Helsinki](http://www.eurail.com/trains-europe/ferries/finnlines): 1095 km
- [Cadiz–La Palma](http://www.trasmediterranea.es): 1382 km
- [Hirsthals–Seyðisfjörður](http://www.smyrilline.com/info/Arrival_-_Departure.aspx): 1504 km
- [Alaska Marine Highway](http://www.dot.state.ak.us/amhs/schedule_pdf.shtml) has some long routes: Selgovia–Dutch Harbor (1096 km), Bellingham–Skagway (1451 km). But nothing ocean-going beats [Bellingham–Homer](http://www.dot.state.ak.us/amhs/doc/schedules/Summer12/CrossGulf_S12.pdf) with **2219 km**. Question is if this is still a ferry considering it doesn't go very often (apparently just three times a year).
- Norwegian Hurtigruten takes cars: [Bergen–Kirkenes](http://www.hurtigruten.com/) which is 1541 km as the crow flies, but at least twice as long with the route it actually takes.

**Even longer:** The river boat from [Omsk to Salekhard](https://severflot.ru/raspisanie-passazhirskie-perevozki/omsk-tobolsk-salekhard-i-obratno) (Siberia, Russia) runs for **2783 km**.  If I'm reading the timetable correctly, the journey takes 6 days (and [a connecting ferry from Salekhard to Antipayuta](https://severflot.ru/raspisanie-passazhirskie-perevozki/salekhard-novyj-port-antipayuta-i-obratno) is another 2 nights and 715 km).  I don't think it takes cars, but I'm not entirely sure about that, as the only other way for people in some communities along the river to bring a car would be by winter road, so maybe there is a provision for that.

There may be other very long river boat journeys in Russia, in particular in Siberia.  *Siberia is big. Really big. You just won't believe how vastly, hugely, mind-bogglingly big it is. I mean, you may think it's a long way down the road to the chemist, but that's just peanuts to Siberia*¹.

See also: *[Overview (map) of Russian long-distance river regular passenger ships in regions too remote for roads or railways](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/18496/2509)*

---

¹After [Douglas Adams](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Space).

Comment: This answer seems to be suffering from link-rot.

Comment: @PeterGreen Unsurprising.  I'm linking to 2012 timetables.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ferries over 1000 km as the bird flies; all take cars unless otherwise noted

- Mauritius to Agalega, 1084 km and https://mauritiusshipping.net, not sure if it takes cars
- ones across the Black Sea, like 1173 km Burgas - Batumi (https://pbm.bg), Constanta - Poti (https://ukrferry.com/en/), 1075 km
- Travemunde to Helsinki by finnlines (1108 km)
- Venice - Patras (with an intermediate stop in Igoumenitsa), by superfast ferriers (1117 km)
- Bellingham - Sitka, 1260 km from Alaska Marine Highway System
- Canary Island ferries, such as the 1300 km Huelva - Tenerife (https://navieraarmas.com/en/)
- Osaka to Shanghai (https://shinganjin.com/en/) being 1338 km (not sure if it takes cars)
- Seydisfjordur - Hirtshals via Torshavn, by Smyril lines and 1519 km
- Russian river ferries (with multiple intermediate stops), e.g. from Krasnoyarsk to Dudinka, 1525 km from pr24.ru, 1463 km from Ust-Kut to Yakutsk by https://Lenaturflot.ru and Kargasok - Salekhard, 1100 km from https://Severflot.ru. Not sure if they take cars
- But the longest I could verify exists and takes cars was Tangier Med - Civitavecchia, a whopping 1643 km by Grandi Navi Veloci (https://gnv.it/en/)