# Overview (map) of Russian long-distance river regular passenger ships in regions too remote for roads or railways

Tags: russia, ferries, maps, riverboats

It appears many of the big Russian rivers have passenger ships going along the river, in areas where roads and railways do not reach.  What I have found so far:

- On the [Yenisey river](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yenisei_River) via [PassazhirRechTrans](http://www.prt24.ru/), such as from [Красноярск to Дудинка](http://www.prt24.ru/sheet/2017-02-20-04-48-45.html)
- On the [Pechora river](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pechora_River), with [RTK Komi](http://www.rtkkomi.ru):
  connectinng Усть-Цильма  (Ust-Tsilma) with Ермица, Чаркабож with Щельяюр, Печора (Pechora) – Аранец (Aranets) – [Усть-Щугер (Ust-Shchuger)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ust-Shchuger) (location of the European cold record at -58.1°C) – Вуктыл (Vuktyl), and Печора (Pechora) with Озерный.
- On the [Lena River](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Yakutsk#By_boat) by [Lenaturflot](http://lenaturflot.ru), such as from [Yakutsk to Tiksi](http://lenaturflot.ru/yakutsk-tiksi-yakutsk-marshrut/), between [Усть — Кут (Ust-Kut) and Пеледуй (Peleduy)](http://lenaturflot.ru/peleduy-ust-kut-peleduy-raspisanie/).
- On the [Ob River](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ob_River) by [Severflot](https://severflot.ru), such as between [Омск (Omsk) to Салехард (Salekhard)](https://severflot.ru/raspisanie-passazhirskie-perevozki/omsk-tobolsk-salekhard-i-obratno), and [also](https://severflot.ru/uslugi/perevozki/passazhirskie-perevozki) routes on the [Irtysh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irtysh_River), [Konda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konda_River), [Kazim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kazim_River), [Severnaya Sosva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Severnaya_Sosva_River), [Lyapin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapin_River), [Nadym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nadym_River),
  and [Vakh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vakh_River) rivers.

It seems such boats could be a suitable way to connect from the Trans-Siberian railway to (even) more remote locations (such as the vicinity of [Lake Vivi](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/11259/2509)), where roads and railways do not reach.  However, I find it difficult to find information about such boats, routes, schedules, etc..  Where can I find an overview, preferably a map, of long-distance boats in Russia?  By long-distance boats I mean boats that run *along* the river for at least some dozens of kilometres, but preferably for several days, as opposed to ferries that simply cross the river from shore to shore.

Note that I'm looking for regular passenger ships, not special tourist cruises.  Specifically, *I'm looking for areas where travel by river is the only way of transportation*, such as in the examples I've shown; there are no roads or railways in these areas.

I don't think this map from [Wikimedia Commons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Siberiariverroutemap.png) shows actual passenger ship routes, just old used routes:

[image: something like this I'm looking for]

So, a map like this but with actually trafficated routes would be nice to see!

Comment: I'll add it as an answer if it's what you want, but realise that most long distance river trips along their rivers - ARE passenger cruises.  As such, I think this site probably covers a lot of it, with several maps: [Cruise Russia and Ukraine](http://www.russia-ukraine-travel.com/cruise-russia.html)

Comment: @MarkMayo Aren't they also used as normal local transportation by villagers along the river, much like the Norwegian [Hurtigruten](http://www.hurtigruten.no) used to be and still is in the far north?  I guess it depends on the definition of a *cruise*, then (to be, a cruise would be purely recreational and focussing on leisure, luxury, and entertainment, as opposed to transportation from A to B).  Those maps seem to be mostly in populated areas, whereas the areas that I mentioned have neither roads nor railways, leaving only rivers for travel.  I've edited the question for enhanced clarity.

Comment: yeah I wasn't sure, so kept it in a comment.  Those areas would be amazing to explore, but also worth remembering that some of the rivers there would be frozen solid for much of the year :/

Comment: @MarkMayo [No problem!](http://www.lonelytraveller.de/nordrussland/nordrusF1.html)

Comment: man, if you get an expedition organised, let me know, I'd be tempted ;)

Comment: There appears to be some sort of an overview on [cruiseinform.ru](http://cruiseinform.ru/cruisepedia/river).

Comment: @MarkMayo As an illustration of the difference between a cruise and a regular passenger journey: With Lenaturflot on the Lena river, a single cruise from Yakutsk to Tiksi and back [starts at 172000 ruble](http://lenaturflot.ru/en/arkticheskiy-kruiz-yakutsk-tiksi-ya-4/), a regular passenger ticket on the same route [starts at 10750 ruble](http://lenaturflot.ru/en/yakutsk-tiksi-yakutsk-tsenyi/). Guess on which one you will meet local Yakut families travelling between villages along the river...!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know there is no such super-site that covers all river routes, since there is no monopoly in river transportation in Russia (unlike train transportation like [RZD.ru](http://rzd.ru) where you can find and book almost everything related to trains).

If you are looking for regular passenger ships then you should search on sites that belong to local river transportation companies. Usually those companies are situated in major cities on the route.
How to find those sites? Take start point and end point on the route and google it. There is however an inconvenience that you must use a translator, because many of these sites are simple static HTML's in Russian.

For example, for the route Krasnoyarsk-Dudinka, here is the site of the transportation company [prt24](http://www.prt24.ru/)

Comment: Even if there is no monopoly, there could be user-contributed sites.  Maybe something for Wikivoyage to coordinate? :)

Comment: @gerrit There are some sites from travel agencies that overview river cruises, but you are interested in regular ships and they belong to local companies.

Comment: Could be a project for Openstreetmap or Rome2rio as well.

Answer (score 4):

An overview of the river routes I was able to find:

## European Russia

### Pechora river

On the [Pechora river](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pechora_River), the company [RTK Komi](http://www.rtkkomi.ru) has:

- [Усть-Цильма (Ust-Tsilma)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ust-Tsilma) – Уег – Верхнее Бугаево – Окунёв Нос – Крестовка – Медвежка – Новый Бор – [Ермица](https://nakarte.me/#m=11/66.90071/52.35329&l=T), see [timetable](http://www.rtkkomi.ru/content/menu/118/Vangyr-raspisanie.pdf)
- [Чаркабож](https://nakarte.me/#m=12/65.70140/54.71157&l=T) – Кипиево – Чика – Няшабож – Пиль-Егор – [Щельяюр](https://www.openstreetmap.org/?mlat=65.3225&mlon=53.41083&zoom=12#map=12/65.3063/53.4279), see [timetable](http://www.rtkkomi.ru/content/menu/118/Schugor-raspisanie.pdf)
- [Печора (Pechora)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pechora) (train station) – Красный Яг – Медвежская – Кедровый Шор – Конецбор – [Аранец (Aranets)](https://nakarte.me/#m=13/64.82967/57.83564&l=T) – Приуральское – Даниловка – Усть Воя – Усть Сонлеск – [Усть-Щугер (Ust-Shchuger)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ust-Shchuger) (location of the European cold record at -58.1°C) – Кырта – Подчерье – [Вуктыл (Vuktyl)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vuktyl) (see [timetable](http://www.rtkkomi.ru/content/menu/118/Schapkina-raspisanie.pdf))
- Печора (Pechora) with Озерный (see [timetable](http://www.rtkkomi.ru/content/menu/118/raspisanie-Pechora-Ozernyi.pdf)), which is just a 10-minute [car ferry](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/87999526).

Openstreetmap also claims [a car ferry to from Щельяюр to Нарьян Мар](https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/4076868), but I can find no evidence this still exists and it appears there are roads there now, so this might have been withdrawn.

## Siberia

### Yenisey river

On the [Yenisey river](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yenisei_River), the company [PassazhirRechTrans](http://www.prt24.ru/) has:

- [Красноярск (Krasnoyarsk)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krasnoyarsk) – [Енисейск / Yeniseysk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yeniseysk) – [Ярцево / Yartsevo](https://nakarte.me/#m=11/60.23555/90.33165&l=T) – [Ворогово / Vogorovo](https://nakarte.me/#m=11/61.01755/89.76105&l=T) – [Бор / Bor](https://nakarte.me/#m=13/61.59648/90.08583&l=T) – Бахта – Чулково – В.Имбатское – Сургутиха – Верещагино – Бакланиха – Костино – [Туруханск /Turukhansk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turukhansk) – Горошиха – Курейка – [Игарка (Igarka)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Igarka) – Потапово – [Дудинка (Dudinka)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dudinka), distance 1992 km, travel time downstream 3 days 14 hours, upstream 5 days 8 hours.  Runs around 20 times per year between July and October.  See [PRT timetable](http://www.prt24.ru/sheet/2017-02-20-04-48-45.html).  Note that Dudinka is a [closed city](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_city).  I don't know the limitations of travelling all the way there, but see [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/130104/2509).
- [Подтесово / Podtyosovo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Podtyosovo) – Енисейск / Yeniseysk –  Анциферово – Усть - Пит – Шишмарево – [Колмогорово / Kolmogorovo](https://nakarte.me/#m=12/59.26737/91.34857&l=T) – Назимово – [Ярцево / Yartsevo](https://nakarte.me/#m=11/60.23555/90.33165&l=T) – Никулино – Зотино – [Ворогово / Vogorovo](https://nakarte.me/#m=11/61.01755/89.76105&l=T) – [Бор / Bor](https://nakarte.me/#m=13/61.59648/90.08583&l=T) (near the occurrence of the [Tunguska event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunguska_event)), 473 km, downstream 8 hours 40 minutes, upstream 10 hours 40 minutes, July to October.  See [PRT timetable](http://www.prt24.ru/sheet/2017-02-20-04-48-45.html).
- [Ярцево / Yartsevo](https://nakarte.me/#m=11/60.23555/90.33165&l=T) – Кривляк – [Майское](https://nakarte.me/#m=12/60.00765/89.45206&l=T), June to September, 108 km on the [Sym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sym_River), 3 hours downstream or 3 hours 40 minutes upstream, see [PRT timetable](http://www.prt24.ru/sheet/2017-02-20-04-48-45.html).
- A line connecting "Торг.центр – Реч.вокзал – Караульная – Известковый – О.Овсянский – Телефонистов – Боровое – Усть-Мана", appears to be a commuter line, not sure, thrice daily April to October, see [PRT timetable](http://www.prt24.ru/sheet/2017-02-20-04-48-45.html).
- Many short [car ferries](http://www.prt24.ru/sheet/paromnye-perepravy.html)

### Lena River

On the [Lena River](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lena_River), the company [Lenaturflot](http://lenaturflot.ru) has:

- [Якутск / Yakutsk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yakutsk) — [Тикси / Tiksi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiksi) (which [may well be](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/130117/2509) the northernmost place one can reach with regular public transport without flying)
  [image: Yakutsk – Tiksi]
  Map boat Yakutsk – Tiksi.  *Source: [Lenaturflot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaReN.jpg)*.
- Усть — Кут (Ust-Kut) – Пеледуй (Peleduy), 765 km, see [timetable](http://lenaturflot.ru/peleduy-ust-kut-peleduy-raspisanie)).
- Пеледуй – Ленск, 211 km, see [timetable](http://lenaturflot.ru/vitim-lensk-vitim-raspisanie/)
- Ленск – Олёкминск, 408 km, see [timetable](http://lenaturflot.ru/lensk-olekminsk-lensk-raspisanie/)

### Ob-Irtysh basin

In Western Siberia on the [Ob River](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ob_River), [Severflot](https://severflot.ru) and other rivers operates [36 lines](https://severflot.ru/raspisanie-passazhirskie-perevozki), including:

- Along the [Irtysh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irtysh_River) and Ob rivers between Омск (Omsk) to Салехард (Salekhard), **2783 km**, see [timetable](https://severflot.ru/raspisanie-passazhirskie-perevozki/omsk-tobolsk-salekhard-i-obratno)
- Along the Ob river and out to the [Gulf of Ob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gulf_of_Ob), between Салехард (Salekhard) and Антипаюта (Antipayuta), 715 km in 40 hours, see [timetable](https://severflot.ru/raspisanie-passazhirskie-perevozki/salekhard-novyj-port-antipayuta-i-obratno)
- Along the [Lyapin river](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapin_River): [Саранпауль](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C) (Saranpaul) – Хурумпауль – Ломбовож – [Сосьва](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%B2%D0%B0_%28%D0%A5%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%29) (Sosva) (see [Lyapin timetable](https://severflot.ru/raspisanie-passazhirskie-perevozki?view=article&id=167:saranpaul-sosva-saranpaul-2&catid=11:raspisaniya-passazhirskie-perevozki))
- Along the [Severnaya Sosva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Severnaya_Sosva_River) river:
  Берёзово / [Beryovozo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beryozovo,_Khanty-Mansi_Autonomous_Okrug) – Шайтанка – Ванзетур – Игрим / [Igrim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Igrim) – Анеева – Сартынья – [Сосьва](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%B2%D0%B0_%28%D0%A5%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%29)
- Other routes on the [Konda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konda_River), [Kazim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kazim_River),  [Nadym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nadym_River),
  and [Vakh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vakh_River) rivers.