# Is there any limitation on foreign nationals travelling by passenger boat Omsk – Salekhard or Salekhard – Antipayuta?

Tags: russia, riverboats, restricted-areas

[Severflot](https://severflot.ru/uslugi/perevozki/passazhirskie-perevozki) in summer and autumn operates passenger boats on the Yenisey and Ob rivers, from Omsk in the south to Antipayuta in the north.  On [this river-forum post](http://river-forum.ru/showthread.php/3351-%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B3%D0%B0-%D0%9A%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%9E%D0%BC%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B4-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%98%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%88%D1%83-%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%B8?highlight=%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B4), someones writes that *Обязательно привезти копию первой страницы паспорта и копию [**свидетельства о рождении**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%BE_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8)* (emphasis mine) (Google translation: "Be sure to bring a copy of the first page of the passport and a copy of the birth certificate").  I would have a па́спорт (passport) in any case, but the need for a *свидетельство о рождении* (birth certificate) makes me wonder if they might limit foreign nationals.  There are certainly [places with travel restrictions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_city) for foreign or even Russian nationals.  On the other hand, the eastern Siberian Lenaturflot [advertises in English](http://lenaturflot.ru/en/yakutsk-tiksi-yakutsk/) that *Also voyage Yakutsk – Tiksi is popular among tourists from Russia and foreign countries. Usually such tourists come to Yakutia without taking a package tour*.
As a foreigner, can I simply buy a ticket on one of those river boats or might some be for Russian nationals only?

Comment: This [decree](http://base.garant.ru/104408/) mentions an area around the Yenisey (excluding the ship channel) so maybe do some map checking plus Wikipedia's article on Closed Cities.

Comment: @mkennedy Right... but I wonder if passengers can still board the ship, just not get off at any of the ports with closed cities.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Have you tried sending an e-mail to Severflot with your question? It seems [they just want to see your ID](https://severflot.ru/kupit-bilet?view=article&id=179:pravila-pokupki-passazhirskikh-biletov&catid=2:bez-kategorii) which should be either a passport for adults OR a birth certificate for children. At first glance it looks more like poor wording of the requirements than an actual ban.

Comment: @undercat No, I might do that if my plans gets more concrete and then I would add an answer here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that Salekhard is neither in [border proximity zone](https://www.yanao.ru/activity/2884/) nor in the [list of territories where international citizens' travel is controlled](http://pravo.gov.ru/proxy/ips/?docbody=&nd=102017268).

Neither is Ob' river waterway.

However, Antipayuta seem to be deeply inside the territory where travel is controlled, which means, you will need a permit obtained from FSB to set foot there. It is also in border proximity zone with similar limitations.

Please see the following map: everything to the right of line requires explicit permit.

[image: Controlled travel area around Salekhard]

Of course, you also need to ask Severflot if they will carry international citizens, either way.

Comment: Does that mean Antipayuta is like a "closed city" (even when it's not a city)?

Comment: No, closed cities is a separate list. However, it is border area so there is little practical difference.

Comment: I'm surprised it counts as border area.  There are plenty of coastal cities in Russia (St. Petersburg, Arkhangelsk, Murmansk, Vladivostok) and I don't think they all count as border area?  Is it just the Arctic Ocean that counts as a border area?

Comment: This list is non-trivial, but we actually have a lot of area count as border area, and it creates all kinds of hassles: for example, Ivangorod and Pechory Pskovskie are both tourist attractions and border areas with limited access.