# Ferries from Iceland to Portugal or Spain

Tags: spain, ferries, iceland, portugal

Does anyone know if there are ferries from Iceland (any harbour) to Portugal or Spain?

Comment: There are roughly 2300 km from the south of Iceland to the north of Spain, that would be very long ferry trip. Comparing with the answer to https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8509/what-is-the-longest-distance-by-car-ferry, actually the longest in the world (I haven't checked if anything has changed since then).

Comment: Take the ferry to Denmark, then the train from there, or, if you feel like doing an excursion with many ferries, train to Netherlands, ferry to England, train to Southampton, ferry to Spain.

Answer (score 13):

The only company I know of that runs regular ferries to Iceland from either Denmark or the Faroe Islands is [Smyril Line](http://www.smyrilline.com). Also, I'm Portuguese and have already been to Iceland and I can tell you I've never heard of a commercial ferry company doing that route.

I also found a website with all the ferries within Iceland, not sure if it is of any value to you: https://www.rent.is/blog/ferries-in-iceland/.

Answer (score 7):

There are no scheduled connections.

[According to ferrylines.com](https://www.ferrylines.com/search/), connections from Iceland go to the Faroe Islands and Denmark, only.